# Modifying the Hovercard jQuery plugin for Facebook iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using the Hovercard jQuery plugin (which can be found [here](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard), see in particular example 7) and it is really very good. I've modified it slightly, but there is one element I'm having trouble finding in the code: the positioning of the box overall. It's not an issue when the element that you hover over is text, but when it becomes an iframe (e.g. a Facebook like button) it positions itself too low.

Can anyone see where this can be modified? It needn't be conditional as the only two elements I am using is the aforementioned iframe and an image of the same size.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the relevant part of my website: http://sas98.user.srcf.net/like/index2.php

Comment: jsfiddle.net/wCrX5 although on the actual version I'm working on the like button on the right hand side doesn't appear and the white box is about 10px lower with the left hand like button hanging out the top.

Comment: Also, on my MacBook there is another identical white box directly below the first one.

Comment: Here is the relevant part of my website instead http://sas98.user.srcf.net/like/index2.php

Answer (score 0):

Since the like button has a predictable height, I would cheat and hard code the offset pixels.

Comment: Whereabouts are the offset pixels?

Comment: According to Chrome web inspector, it is 24px tall, so that should be the offset.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
.hc-details-open-left{
      margin-right: -20px;
      margin-top: -8px;
}
```